# How to manually resolve dependencies in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, dnx

I'm writing some custom middleware that requires some services to be registerend and I want to unit test this.

The middleware basically catches all unhandled exceptions and logs to a persistence store. In this particular case, it's being saved into the database.

I have a manager which talks to a store, and the store is being injected into the constructor of the manager:

```
public ErrorManager(IErrorStore<TError, TKey> store)
{
    _store = store;
}
```

My middleware is being injected in the following way:

```
public static AspNetErrorLoggingBuilder<TError, TKey>     AddAspNetErrorLogging<TError, TKey>(this IServiceCollection services)
    where TError : class, IErrorEntry<TKey>, new()
    where TKey : class
{
    // Get the object that will hold the configuration.
    var aspNetErrorLoggingConfiguration = new     AspNetErrorLoggingConfiguration();

    // Add all the services that are required.
    services.AddSingleton<IErrorStore<TError, TKey>, MemoryErrorStore<TError, TKey>>();
    services.TryAddTransient<ErrorManager<TError, TKey>, ErrorManager<TError, TKey>>();
    services.AddInstance(aspNetErrorLoggingConfiguration);

    // Get the service descriptor of the error store.
    var errorStoreDescriptor = services[services.Count - 1];

    // Return a builder to configure the DocTrails Power Archive.
    return new AspNetErrorLoggingBuilder<TError, TKey>(services, typeof(TError), errorStoreDescriptor);
}
```

You see here that I'm adding a Singleton of the store to the dependency injection container.

Now, in my unit tests, I do create a Test Server, adds the middleware, and fire a request that will result in an unhandled exception:

```
public async Task Use_Should_UseMemoryErrorStore()
{
    // Defines a provider to retrieve all the registered services.
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;

    // Create a test server and inject the middleware.
    var testServer = TestServer.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.UseAspNetErrorLoggingMiddleware<ErrorEntry, string>();

        // Defines the response of the server.
        builder.Run(context =>
        {
            throw new Exception("Unhandled exception");
        });
    }, services =>
    {
        services.AddAspNetErrorLogging<ErrorEntry, string>();
        serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    });

    // Create the client that can fire requests to the server.
    var client = testServer.CreateClient();

    // Request a single page (this will cause an exception to be thrown).
    await client.GetAsync("/");
}
```

On debugging, everything seems fine as the exception get logged into memory.

When I manually resolve the dependency and uses a count on it, I do get 0;

```
// Get the Error Manager service and verify that a single entry has been added.
var errorManagerInstance = serviceProvider.GetService<ErrorManager<ErrorEntry, string>>();
var errorsCount = await errorManagerInstance.GetCountAsync();

Assert.Equal(1, errorsCount);
```

Basically, the instance which I'm retrieving through the `IServiceProvider` is not the same instance as the one used in the middleware, altough it's registered as a Singleton.

How should this be solved?

**Edit**

It seems to behave differently when registering an instance directly rather than a Singleton.

```
var memoryStoreInstance = new MemoryErrorStore<TError, TKey>();

// Add all the services that are required.
services.AddInstance(typeof (IErrorStore<TError, TKey>), memoryStoreInstance);
```

Then, the unit test passed and the same object is used.

Kind regards